# Throw the errors away and run it in the background silently

Tags: process, io-redirection

I'd like to retrieve all the 'html' books using command `find`,
additionally, place it in the background without distracting my attention.

```
    $ find / -type f -iregex '.*html.*\.pdf' > html_books.md &
```

Nevertheless, `permission denied` errors disturb me constantly.

```
    $ find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
    find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
```

As a solotion, I redirect the stderrs

```
    $ find / -type f -iregex '.*html.*\.pdf' > html_books.md 2>&1 &
```

Consequently, `html_books.md` become a mess.

How to throw the errors away silently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just blackhole the errors by redirecting stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
find / -type f -iregex '.*html.*\.pdf' > html_books.md 2>/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the standard error stream separately from the standard output stream, to `/dev/null`, [as dr01 showed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434024/116858), or you can prune those directories that you don't have access to:

```
find / '(' -type d ! '(' -executable -readable ')' -prune ')' -o \
    -type f -name '*html.*.pdf' >html_books.md
```